# wp_query a single custom post type?

Tags: wp-query

How does one get a custom post by id? FYI: I am passing a particular post id through a form and it's performing an ajax call.

I'd like to retrieve just one post and grab the title:

```
<?php 
// E.g. $loc = 700
$args = array('post_id'=>$loc, 'post_type'=>'seminars', 'limit'=> '1');

$loop = new WP_Query($args);
// Start loop for seminar posts
$loop->the_post();
echo the_title();

// returns just one post and it's not the right custom post
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'post_id'` is not a [valid page/post parameter for `WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters). Try using `p` or `post__in` instead:

```
array(
    'p' => 700
)
```

or

```
array(
    'post__in' => array(
        700
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need only title then why not to use get_the_title function ?

```
//$post_ID = 700
<?php echo get_the_title($post_ID); ?>
```

There is **<strike>NO</strike>** way we can pass post-ID as parameter to [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters) function.